# Matrix Inner Product Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite

Verbatim from my textbook

---

**DEFINITION**

Let A be a symmetric positive-definite $n × n$ matrix. For two n-vectors v and w, define the
A-inner product:
$$(v,w)_A = v^TAw $$
The vectors v and w are A-conjugate if $(v,w)_A = 0$.

Note that the new inner product inherits the properties of symmetry, linearity, and
positive-definiteness from the matrix A. Because A is symmetric, so is the A-inner product:

$(v,w)_A = v^TAw = (v^TAw)^T = w^TAv = (w,v)_A$. The A-inner product is also linear, and
positive-definiteness follows from the fact that if A is positive-definite, then
$$(v,v)_A = v^TAv > 0$$
if $v \neq 0$.

---

I get the symmetry, but why is it that $(v,w)_A$ is positive definite because $(v,v)_A$ is positive definite? How does that follow?

Comment: Check again how the psd condition is formulated in the definition of scalar products.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for an inner product to "always be positive", as shown below for your specific case:

Suppose $\langle u, v \rangle > 0$.

Then $\langle u, -v\rangle = u^TA(-v) = -u^TAv = -\langle u, v\rangle < 0$

In the context of inner products, the property that $\langle v, v\rangle > 0$ for $v\neq0$ is referred to as posite-definiteness (and it has nothing to do with $\langle v, w\rangle$).